# proving logic without using truth table

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Without using truth table, show that 
the conjunction of $(1) \; q \cdot (r \vee s\cdot t) \supset u$ and $u \vee r \supset p$ implies (2) $q \supset p \vee s$

we allows "u" count as sentence letter here

I assumes that if $ p \vee s$ is False the (2) will be False. Then, I don't know how to continue, can someone please show me how?

Comment: Instead of requiring "without using truth table", it would be better to say what method you will be using.

Answer (score 0):

*Comment*

If you want to prove it by contradiction, you have to assume the conclusion false, i.e. assume $q$ True and $p \lor s$ False; this implies both $p$ and $s$ False.

But $p$ False implies, in order that the 2nd premise is True, that also $u \lor r$ is False, and thus both $u$ and $r$ False.

Thus, up to now :

> TRUE : $q$ and FALSE : $p, r, s, u$.

Finally, consider the 1st premise : $s$ False implies $s \land t$ False, and thus, with $r$ False, also $r \lor (s \land t)$ is False.

In turn, also $q \land [r \lor (s \land t)]$ is False, and thus the 1st premise is True.

So, no contradiction at all...